# Apache htaccess strange behaviour with rewrite rules

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I don't know what's going on but I cannot make use of the rewrite module. In my .htaccess file I have a rule like this: `RewriteRule ^test$ test.php`. If `test.php` does not exists I get a 404 error saying that it cannot find the `test.php` file, which is correct (also, the rule matched). After I add the `test.php` file when I access the `test` url I also get a 404 not found, but this time is telling me that it cannot find `/test` (which makes me think that rule doesn't matches).

What's the issue ? I don't follow. I've tried anything but I cannot make it to work properly.

Comment: What are you attempting to accomplish with your rewrite rule? Basically, you are saying that the URL has to ONLY contain the word "test" and that will be rewritten to "test.php".

Comment: yes, I know what the rule does, I used `test` to imply that this is an example, but the problem exists with any rule.

Comment: If that is the only rule that is supposed to match in that case, try adding a "[R,L]" to the end of the rule. Also, you might increase the log level for this. Keep in mind that levels of 3 and below are utterly useless, but the higher will show you what and why things happen.

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work. I don't know why it's doing this. it's the first time when something like this happens to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing this behaviour. In the vhost configuration file I had to put  `-MultiViews` to the `Options` rule. Now it's working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

`/test` is not `^test$`, it should be `^/test$`

**Edit**: Have you tried this: `RewriteRule ^/test$ /test.php [R,L]` ?

Comment: no, sorry, doesn't solve the problem

Comment: do you have the `[R,L]` after the rule, as Eirik suggested? Furthermore, do you have `RewriteEngine On`?

Comment: yes, I have it.

Comment: Are you sure the browser is not putting a trailing slash at the request?

Comment: yes, the browser is not altering the url. I really can't figure out this strange behaviour. this is a new environment, maybe could be something related to permissions ? is it possible ?

Comment: Honestly, your best bet is to increase the logging for mod_rewrite and examine what the logs tell you.